# Not being able to push Git files to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am faced with an error message every time I push my git files to Heroku.

The steps I have taken are:

1. heroku login
2. heroku keys:add
3. heroku create
4. git push heroku master

The error message is as follows:

```
           Could not detect rake tasks
           remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against   your app
           remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
           remote:  !     rake aborted!

          Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
          remote:
          remote: Verifying deploy...
          remote:
          remote: !       Push rejected to project1-app.
          remote:
          To https://git.heroku.com/project1-app.git
          ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
          error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/project1-app.git'
```

Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read  more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

 # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
 # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

 # Use Unicorn as the app server
 # gem 'unicorn'

  # Use Capistrano for deployment
  # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

  group :development, :test do
   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger              console
    gem 'byebug'
     end

    group :development do
    # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in  views
   gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

   # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the  background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  end
```

Comment: Have you tried running `bundle exec rake -P` as suggested?

Comment: Hi Jonathan I get this error message when i run that:                                     rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'.

Comment: Have you done the basics like `bundle install` ?

Comment: Can you include your gem file ?

Comment: Hi Shyam Bhimani, I included my gem file. It's above.

Comment: was my below answer helped you to solve your problem ? @stevey1993

Comment: Thanks Shyam Bhimani. It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have not updated your bundle may be after some editing in gem file. In order to make your bundle up-to date with your current gem file run below command

(1) `bundle install`

(2) `bundle update`

once your bundle is updated you can run

(3) `heroku login`

(4) `heroku create`

(5) `git add .`

(6) `git commit -am "some comment"`

(7) `git push heroku master`

(8) `heroku open`